# Login works on localhost but doesn't on Azure web app service?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I created a simple register, login and dashboard web application using ASP.NET Core. Everything works fine on localhost. I can create a new account, login and view the Dashboard page. However when I update changes to my Github repository which is connected to my Azure web app service then I can view the login page but I cannot login.I see page with HTTP 500 error message. The build which is provided by Github is successful and no error messages were shown. Help me get rid of that error. Is there anything on the Azure Control Panel I can use to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According your description, you can deployed the webapp via GitHub action successfully. And you also can view the login page, it means this issue is not related to the deployment.

I guess you also can't register a new user. The issue should be related to you don't have a correct database connection string. Generally we could set the DB connections in Azure portal, it could rewrite the settings inside the application. It also can protect your private information.

[image]

You also could enable the detailed logs, then check it.

[image]

I have an easy way for you to let your local SQL server can be accessed, [Ngrok is a good tool](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: Yes the issue could be the connection string, the connection string is specified in the application's json file. There is code in the startup file to create a new one if it does not exist. Does azure allow scripts to create the database files

Comment: Almost testing your answer.

Comment: @QingGuo If you could share more details(pls hide sensitive information), I am willing to help you check it.

Comment: Okay, should the name of the connection string I specify in Azure be the same as the one defined in my code?

Comment: @QingGuo The code in your code is generally applicable to the development and testing environment. After deployment, if it is set in the azure portal, it will overwrite the configuration in the appconfig.json file. If the connectionstring is not set in the azure portal, the application will use the settings in appconfig.json.

Comment: Then it's not a connection string issue as my connection string is specified in the json file of my project. However I do not check if the environment is production or development in my code. This could be the reason as to why